# Making a Yhatzee game, array won't show up on screen

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, object, methods

Ok so I just started learning ruby and I'm making a Yhatzee game, now this is where I'm currently at:

```
class  Yhatzee

 def dices
    @dices.to_a= [
    dice1=rand(1..6),
    dice2=rand(1..6),
    dice3=rand(1..6),
    dice4=rand(1..6),
    dice5=rand(1..6)
    ]
  end

  def roll_dice
    @dices.to_a.each do |dice|
      puts dice
    end
  end
end

x = Yhatzee.new
puts x.roll_dice
```

Now the reason i typed .to_a after the array is i kept getting a "uninitialized variable @dices" error, and that seemed to fix it, i have no idea why.

anyways on to my question, i currently don't get any errors but my program still won't print anything to the screen. I expected it to print out the value of each dice in the array... any idea what I'm doing wrong? It seems to work when i do it in a procedural style without using classes or methods so i assumed it might work if i made the 'dices' method public. But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here. Firstly `@dices` is `nil` because it is not set anywhere. Thus when you call `@dices.to_a` you will get `[]`. Also the dices method will not work either because `nil` does not have a `to_a=` method and the local variables you are assigning in the array will be ignored.

It seems a little reading is in order but I would do something like the following: (Not the whole game just refactor of your code)

```
class  Yhatzee
  def dice
    @dice = Array.new(5){rand(1..6)}
  end
  def roll_dice
    puts dice
  end
end

x = Yhatzee.new
puts x.roll_dice
```

There are alot of additional considerations that need to be made here but this should at least get you started. Small Example of how I would recommend expanding your logic: (I did not handle many scenarios here so don't copy paste. Just wanted to give you a more in depth look)

```
require 'forwardable'
module Yahtzee
  module Display
    def show_with_index(arr)
      print arr.each_index.to_a
      print "\n"
      print arr
    end
  end
  class Roll
    include Display
    extend Forwardable 
    def_delegator :@dice, :values_at
    attr_reader :dice
        def initialize(dice=5)
            @dice = Array.new(dice){rand(1..6)}
        end
        def show
      show_with_index(@dice)
        end
    end
  class Turn
    class << self
      def start
        t = Turn.new
        t.show
        t
      end
    end
    attr_reader :rolls
    include Display
    def initialize
      @roll = Roll.new
      @rolls = 1
      @kept = []
    end
    def show
      @roll.show
    end
    def roll_again
      if available_rolls_and_dice
        @rolls += 1
        @roll = Roll.new(5-@kept.count)
        puts "Hand => #{@kept.inspect}"
        show
      else
        puts "No Rolls left" if @rolls == 3
        puts "Remove a Die to keep rolling" if @kept.count == 5
        show_hand
      end 
    end
    def keep(*indices)
      @kept += @roll.values_at(*indices)
    end
    def show_hand
      show_with_index(@kept)
    end
    def remove(*indices)
      indices.each do |idx| 
        @kept.delete_at(idx)
      end
      show_hand
    end
    private 
      def available_rolls_and_dice
        @rolls < 3 && @kept.count < 5
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey thank's for the fix, i will try not to look at your expansions unless i get stuck, I'm doing this mostly as an exercise, it's my first actual project really. I have a question tough. Basically it seems to me that what you did was really just calling the method 'dice' instead of calling the actual variable '@dice' i don't quite understand why that worked while calling the variable didn't. Also when you solve the problem like that is there any reason to actually make the '@dice' array an instance variable?

Comment: @MariusBelkhirMahiout the reason calling the variable did not work is because it was not set when you called it so it was `nil` and `nil.to_a` produces an empty array. Calling the method returns the Array thus it works. Technically you do not need the instance variable when calling like this but you probably want to hold onto the dice so you can interact with it later.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with this code is that you are trying to use the @dices instance variable inside of the `roll_dice` method, however you are not defining the instance variable anywhere (anywhere that is being used). You have created the `dices` method but you are not actually instantiating it anywhere. I have outlined a fix below:

```
class  Yhatzee

  def initialize
    create_dices
  end

  def roll_dice
    @dices.each do |dice|
      puts dice
    end
  end

  private

  def create_dices
    @dices = Array.new(5){rand(1..6)}
  end

end

x = Yhatzee.new
x.roll_dice
```

I have done some simple refactoring:

1. Created an initialize method, which creates the @dice instance variable on the class initialization.
2. Made the 'dices' method more descriptive and changed the method visibility to private so only the class itself is able to create the @dice.
3. Cleaned up the creation of the dices inside of the @dice instance variable
4. I have omitted the .to_a from the roll_dice method, now that we create the variable from within the class and we know that it is an array and it will be unless we explicitly redefine it.

## UPDATE

Although I cleaned up the implementation of the class, it was kindly pointed out by @engineersmnky that I oversaw that the roll would return the same results each time I called the roll_dice function, I have therefore written two functions which will achieve this, one that defines an instance variable for later use and one that literally just returns the results.

```
class  Yhatzee

  def roll_dice
   @dice = Array.new(5){rand(1..6)} # You will have access to this in other methods defined on the class
   @dice.each {|dice| puts dice }
  end

  def roll_dice_two
    Array.new(5){rand(1..6)}.each {|dice| puts dice } # This will return the results but will not be stored for later use
  end

end

x = Yhatzee.new
x.roll_dice
x.roll_dice # Will now return a new result
```

Comment: excellent explanation but from a logical standpoint `@dices` is now fixed to that set. Shouldn't roll return different results every time? Also puts inside an each loop for an Array will have the same impact as just calling `puts ARRAY_HERE`

Comment: Yes thank you for pointing this out I completely oversaw this point. I have now amended my answer. Regarding the loop, I didn't actually know this was the case however after looking at it I think I prefer to use a loop just for ease of reading.